# Efficiency of using subprocess in conjunction with threads, in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I am using Python 2.7.  I have a multi-threaded program where the threads launch commands using the `subprocess` module.  The processes run on the system and report data occasionally to the threads.  The majority of the work is done in the processes - the threads just take information from the processes and write them to a file, for example.

I understand that there are limitations on using multithreading with python.  But in this case, I expect that all the heavy lifting will be done by the system (Linux), because the subprocesses launched are doing the CPU-intensive stuff.  So the threads don't have to carry any load, and therefore should not be a bottleneck.

Is my understanding of using threads and subprocesses together in Python accurate?  I think a foundational part of my understanding is that these different subprocesses can run on different cores, so even if the threads are bound to one core, the processes will run efficiently, and the threads can collect information from them as it becomes available.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Python's GIL only lets one thread run at a time but that rule only applies to the python process - all of the subprocesses run independently. Since the python threads are mostly just waiting for data from the subprocesses, they don't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the subprocesses just handle the data processing themselves? Passing stuff back to the process requires extra [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) and the overhead of serialisation and deserialisation, which can become significant if you have a lot of work to pass back to the main process. It might be easier to use threads in the subprocesses rather than pay this penalty.

There is something important to note, however. Although I/O-bound code (file writes, sending and receiving data on a socket, etc.) won't run into bottlenecks with the Global Interpreter Lock, CPU-bound tasks will. See [Jesse Noller's blog post on threads](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) and [the Python Wiki's article on the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) for more information about threading issues.

Comment: There are lots of reasons why the subprocesses might be a poor choice for handling data from their own stdout/stderr pipes. Perhaps the main program is logging and wants the information interleaved in a single file or is taking aggregate data for its own processing needs. Suppose these are third party processes that can't be modified. Pipelining data through multiple processes is a time-honored linux/unix tradition.

Comment: @tdelaney He said he was using `subprocess` in his own application, therefore I presume he has full control. Yes, passing data via pipelines is a time-honoured Unix tradition, but it's not always the most efficient way to do processing.